# remove all instances of _000 from multiple files

Tags: files, scripting, rename, recursive

Had to recover my music library from a HDD which died.... got everything I wanted but all music track names have _000 added at the end.

I really don't fancy going through 8000 individual music tracks and choosing to rename in order to remove the _000 string

How can I search the entire Music folder containing all the album sub-directories and remove every instance of _000 on all the individual track names?

Answer (score 2):

```sh
cd Music/..    &&
mkdir Music2   &&
pax -'rwls|\([^/]\)_000$|\1|p' Music Music2
```

If run from `Music`'s parent directory, the above commands will create a directory called `Music2` then mirror `Music`'s path structure in `Music2` w/ hardlinks while removing any occurrence of `_000` found at the tail of any filename therein.

Afterward you'll have basically two routes to `Music`'s contents in `Music/..` - one in which some files are named with trailing `_000` strings, and one in which there is one fewer `_000` at the tail of each filename than there is in the other *(except for files named only `_000` which are not altered)* - but the actual files are untouched. If you find that `Music2/Music` suits you better - `rm -rf Music` and `mv Music2/Music Music` afterward.

The assumption is that all of `Music`'s contents are located on the same mounted filesystem and that it supports hardlinks.

The `perl-rename` used below is the one which can be found on [cpan.org](http://cpan.org) at [~pederst/rename](http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename/). I installed it on an Arch Linux system with [`pacman`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/perl-rename/). Now, I'm told there is another, *safer* perl-script by the same name which can also be found at [cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.20](http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.20/). but I experienced no success with making that one work at all. This failure is more likely to do with my being perl-inept than anything else though.

Anyway, here's a little case study on the dangers of scripted rename solutions versus hardlinking based on a pattern.

```sh
mkdir Music Music2
echo file1 >Music/file
echo file2 >Music/file_000
pax -'rwls|_000$||p' Music Music2
```

I use the `p`rint flag for the `-s`ubstitute option for `pax` above so `pax` prints *only* the names of the files it changes - though it links all of them. It prints:

```
Music/file_000 >> Music/file
```

Now let's see how we did:

```
grep . /dev/null Music/* Music2/Music/*
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Music/file:file1
Music/file_000:file2
Music2/Music/file:file2
```

Uhoh. The result of linking `file` from `file_000` overwrote the dentry for a previously existent `file` when running the mirror op. But in this case the original link still exists - and so the file does as well. Besides retaining a copy dentry copy in the file's existing directory, `pax` *(by default)* `-p`reserves all file attributes that  it can regardless for those files which it must create or copy, as it must create directories *(which cannot be hardlinked)* and if the source is on a different file system *(which can be avoided entirely with `-X`)* it must copy.

And so the two different directories can be compared *after the fact* for differences *before* any unalterable changes are made. And with the `p`rint flag you can take the results it hands you and just cross-reference those to any existing originals - if they exist, you're at least a file shy in your new target.

On the other hand, though:

```sh
find Music -name \*_000 -exec perl-rename 's/_000$//' {} +
grep . /dev/null Music/*
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Music/file:file2
```

The same is not true when the *last* filesystem link for a file is overwritten - that file is history.

Answer (score 2):

Although mikesrv solution is much better and safer I think this can be done also with [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename):

```
find Music/ -type f -name '*_000' -print0 | xargs -r0 rename -v '_000' ''
```

But there are still potential problems as mentioned, for example `album_00020_000` will be renamed to `album20` which obviously is not the desired behaviour.
I think on debian distribution was a `perl` tool [rename](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?rename) which could do it. But unfortunately I can not find a way how to install it. So I found following `perl` script [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch09_10.htm) which can suffice:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# rename - Larry's filename fixer
$op = shift or die "Usage: rename expr [files]\n";
chomp(@ARGV = <STDIN>) unless @ARGV;
for (@ARGV) {
    $was = $_;
    eval $op;
    die $@ if $@;
    rename($was,$_) unless $was eq $_;
}
```

So you can make this script executable and run:

```
find Music/ -type f -name '*_000' | /path_to_script/rename.pl 's/_000$//'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command to enumerate files in a directory and its subdirectories recursively. There are several ways to rename files. You can use the Linux [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) command:

```
find Music -depth -name '*_000' -exec rename _000 '' {} \;
```

This removes the first occurrence of `_000` in each file name. Beware that if you had files whose name contains `_000` in the middle, this won't give you the desired name.

On Debian and derivatives (Ubuntu, Mint, …), the `rename` command is a different one; the Linux one is called `rename.ul`, and the `rename`one can be used this way (which always removes the `_000` at the end even if there's one in the middle):

```
find Music -depth -name '*_000' -exec rename 's/_000$//' {} +
```

An easier way to rename these files is to install [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) (available in most distributions) and use its [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) function. Run `autoload -U zmv` (or put it in `~/.zshrc`) then

```
zmv 'Music/**/*_000' '${f%_000}'
```